# Error while installing PostGIS on RHEL_5?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I am trying to install PostGIS on a RHEL_5 system and failing at it miserably. The way I am trying to install it is as follows. I copy over all the artifacts of postgresql server as in the bin, lib, share directories of postgresql server in a directory called pgql and I place it in the root directory i.e /pgsql is the directory which contains things like pg_config and all the other libs and bins that one gets by installing postgresql using the standard installation. All the dependencies of PostGIS get installed successfully using the standard build process of `./configure --prefix=/pgsql, make and make install` but when I issue the following command for building PostGIS using the same process:

```
./configure --with-gdalconfig=/pgsql/bin/gdal-config --with-geosconfig=/pgsql/bin/geos-config --with-projdir=/pgsql --with-jsondir=/pgsql --with-pgconfig=/pgsql/bin/pg_config
```

I get the following error in the configure step :

```
checking PostgreSQL version... PostgreSQL 9.6
checking libpq-fe.h usability... no
checking libpq-fe.h presence... no
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
configure: error: could not find libpq-fe.h"
```

to remedy this error I tried placing the include files in the include directory of postgresql by find the appropriate path using

```
/pgsql/bin/pg_config --includedir
```

and then when I try to install PostGIS, it still fails. Can anyone suggest some workaround to build PostGIS using this non-standard approach of building PostGIS?

Edit: When I try to add all the include files which includes the libpq-fe.h and libpq headers as well along with other header I get the following error when configuring PostGIS

```
checking for PQserverVersion in -lpq... no
configure: error: could not find libpq
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken there is a seperate postgresql-devel package on RHEL that contains the required headers and libs to build other software against postgresql. Try `yum install postgresql-devel`

Comment: I did install that but that doesn't solve this problem, because installation of the devel package installs the libpq and associated binaries in /usr/bin and I don't want to build against the pg_config present in /usr/bin but the pg_config present in the directory pgsql that I created :(

Comment: and by default it installs the PGSQL 9.2 as the version of the Postgresql server

Answer (score 2):

You need `libpq.so` in `/pgsql/bin/pg_config --libdir`.

If that file is there, check if all its dependencies are present:

```
ldd /pgsql/lib/libpq.so
```

Generally speaking, you are using a highly unorthodox and problematic way of building PostGIS.

Get a development machine that has the same Linux distribution and version as the target system and install PostgreSQL in the normal way. Then all your problems will probably vanish.

Comment: Oh, I see that libpq.so is present in the lib directory but when I do ldd libpq.so I see the following output                                                                      "linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffd78bdc000)
        libssl.so.1.0.0 => not found
        libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => not found
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f82c0e6c000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000560b15b73000)
"

Comment: To remedy that I installed openssl package and that proceeded the configuration a little bit forward, also I set the appropriate LD_LIBRARY_PATH and PATH variables but then I ran into this issue lpq... yes
checking for xml2-config... /pgsql/bin/xml2-config
checking libxml/tree.h usability... yes
checking libxml/tree.h presence... yes
checking for libxml/tree.h... yes
checking libxml/parser.h usability... yes
checking libxml/parser.h presence... yes
checking for xmlInitParser in -lxml2... no
configure: error: could not find libxml2